# Vector bundle on a simply connected space

Tags: general-topology

Is vector bundle of any dimension on a simply connected topological space unique?
I also want to know if it is, then what machinery do we need at hand to archive this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need the space to be contractible. Example : the tangent bundle on $S^2
$ is not trivial.

Comment: How about then a not compact, but simply connected space?

Comment: I believe this is still the same problem : take $S^2 \vee S^2$ and delete one point in one copy of $S^2$. Your space is not compact and simply connected but same example work I think. 

In general, vector bundle of rank $r$ are topologically classified by homotopy class of map $X \to Gr(r, \infty)$ (the infinite Grassmanian). So if you have non-trivial homotopy group it is probably always possible to build a non-trivial vector bundle by building a non-trivial map $X \to Gr(r, \infty)$.

Comment: Interesting. I need more study though. Thanks.

Comment: I would advice Milnor's book about characteristic classes which is probably a bit long but a really good reference for vector bundles (I know only the first chapters but they are already very interesting !)

Comment: Thanks. I actually have chosen the book to read through this semester.